# Use result of a foreach loop

Tags: c#

New to c#. How can I use the result of the foreach loop. I want to Insert the result into my data table.

Give a name to column to be inserted

```
foreach (DataRow row in objDataset1.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    string strValue = row["code"].ToString();        
}

sc.Open();
cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into Table (Code, v1, v2, v3) values('" + strValue + "','" + ckv1.IsChecked.ToString() + "','" + ckv2.IsChecked.ToString() + "', '" + txtv3.Text + "')", sc);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: What do you want to happen if there's more than one row in the table? Presumably you'd want to insert multiple rows, right? Note that you should use parameterized SQL rather than constructing SQL in this way.

Comment: Are you only wanting *one* `strValue` from however many rows are in the table?

Comment: **Hint**: you don't need to call `ToString()` when concatenating some value with other string

Comment: better use [SqlParameter](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter) for values in queries

Comment: There will be many rows. Insert command should insert all rows into table.

Comment: To echo what others have said: using string concatenation like that to put data into an sql query is **very bad**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are much safer with a parameterized query. And if you use a `using block` that will make sure to dispose your connection at the end of it.

```
using(SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection("yourConnectionString"))
{

   cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into [tbl] (Code, v1, v2, v3) Values(@code, @v1, @v2, @v3)", sc);

   cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@code", SqlDbType.VarChar));
   cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@v1", SqlDbType.Bit));
   cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@v2", SqlDbType.Bit));
   cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@v3", SqlDbType.Bit));
   sc.Open();

   foreach (DataRow row in objDataset1.Tables[0].Rows)
   {

        //Assign the values for above parameters here.
        cmd.Parameters["@code"].Value = row["code"].ToString();
        cmd.Parameters["@v1"].Value = valueForV1;
        cmd.Parameters["@v2"].Value = valueForV2;
        cmd.Parameters["@v3"].Value = valueForV3;

        //Execute the command
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
   }
}
```

**Note:** if v1, v2 and v3 are bit fields in the database, you should pass them as boolean values without using .ToString() method.

Comment: Putting the 'new SqlCommand' inside the loop is inefficient; all of those command objects will exist throughout the life of the procedure, which could cause problems on your SQL Server.

Comment: Kaf, I get the error: The SqlParameterCollection only accepts non-null SqlParameter type objects, not String objects.

Comment: Try now, I have changed `cmd.Parameters.Add("name")` to `cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("name", dataType))`, that should sort that out. Make sure parameter datatypes are matching with the database fields they are inserting into.

Comment: Thanks Kaf, your a star!

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely that your C# dataset originated from the Sql databaes in the first place. If so, the most effective way to do this is to build a single query:

```
string sql = "Insert into Table (Code, v1, v2, v3) " + 
                " SELECT code, v1, v2, v3 FROM <this part resembles your original query>";
```

Comment: Hi no it originated from an excel sheet.

Answer (score 0):

```
var codes = objDataset1.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                       .Select(r => r.Field<string>("code"));

if (!code.Any())
    return;


var sql = "INSERT INTO Table (Code, v1, v2, v3) VALUES (@code, @v1, @v2, @v3)";
sc.Open();

foreach(var code in codes)
{        
    cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, sc);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@code", code);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@v1", ckv1.IsChecked);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@v2", ckv2.IsChecked);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@v3", txtv3.Text);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Also consider to use [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) which creates command and adds parameters to it automatically:

```
var v1 = ckv1.IsChecked;
var v2 = ckv2.IsChecked;
var v3 = txtv3.Text;

foreach(var code in codes)
    sc.Execute(sql, new { code, v1, v2, v3 });
```

Comment: This is going to create a new cmd object and add parameters for each and every record of `codes`, instead I think it would be efficient if they are added before the loop and assign the values within the loop.

Comment: @Kaf maybe your code is a little more efficient, but I think it's really insignificant comparing to network query to database and IO operations on server. Keeping all in one place looks more readable to me

Comment: @Kaf agree, that worth mentioning :)

Answer (score 0):

Putting the 'new SqlCommand' inside the loop is inefficient; all of those command objects will exist throughout the life of the procedure, which could cause problems on your SQL Server.  Try:
 
(1) Create your SqlCommand outside of the loop 
(2) Create a SQLParameter, outside of the loop again:

```
SqlParameter myParam = cmd.Parameters.Add("@myValue", SqlDbType.VarChar);
```

(3) in your loop:

```
myParam.Value = strValue;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```